# Scanning input in a for-loop

Tags: java

I'm having trouble counting the number of integers that the user put to concatenate them.

```
int sum = 0, counter;

System.out.println("enter between 1 to 3 digits:");
counter = scan.nextInt();
for(int i=0;i<counter;i++){
    sum = sum + scan.nextInt();
}
System.out.println(sum);
```

This not only stops once because of `nextInt` but I can't figure out a way to actually count how many integers the user put.

For example:

> Enter between 1 to 3 digits : 2 3 3
>
> sum = 8

Comment: I would use scan.nextLine() to read an entire line of text, then .split(" ") to get each number and add them up.

Comment: One immediate problem I see is that you are looping up to counter, which is the first number the user input... which makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
counter = scan.nextInt();
for(int i=0;i<counter;i++){
    sum = sum + scan.nextInt();
}
```

you could use

```
int[] input = new int[3]; //creates array on intergers
while(scan.hasNext()) //loops while there is still input left
{
    input[counter] = Interger.parseInt(scan.next()); //sets input[counter] to the next integer (separated by a space)
    counter++; //increments counter
}
for(int i = 0; i < counter; i++) //loops <amount of integers put in> times
{
    sum += input[i]; //adds input[i] to the total
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So you are accepting the first integer input but not adding it to the sum. Do you want your first integer to tell you how many numbers the user wants to enter? If yes then your code is correct.

In other case if you want to just add all the numbers then you have to do a small change-

```
System.out.println("enter between 1 to 3 digits:");
String s= scan.nextLine();
String ss[] = s.split(" ");
for (String w:ss)
   sum = sum + Integer.parseInt(w);
System.out.println(sum);
```